# Curl URL into vb.net

Tags: vb.net, curl, httpwebrequest

Hi i'm trying to find a solution how to implement the below curl in vb.net:

curl -X 'GET' \ 'https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=bitcoin&vs_currencies=usd&include_market_cap=false&include_24hr_vol=false&include_24hr_change=false&include_last_updated_at=false&precision=full' \ -H 'accept: application/json'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `System.Net.Http` you can do that as follows:

```
Private Sub GetBtcPrice()

    Using client As System.Net.Http.HttpClient = New System.Net.Http.HttpClient

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("accept", "application/json")
        Dim sb As New StringBuilder
        sb.Append("?")
        sb.Append("ids=bitcoin&")
        sb.Append("vs_currencies=usd&")
        sb.Append("include_market_cap=false&")
        sb.Append("include_24hr_vol=false&")
        sb.Append("include_24hr_change=false&")
        sb.Append("include_last_updated_at=false&")
        sb.Append("precision=full")

        Dim response As HttpResponseMessage = client.GetAsync("https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price" & sb.ToString).GetAwaiter().GetResult()
        Dim sResponse As String = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult()
        Console.WriteLine("response: " & sResponse)

    End Using


End Sub
```

Comment: Both answers work, however using string builder makes it more flexible!

Comment: @JohnPaulAttard agree with you. More readable than one line .

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim webClient As New System.Net.WebClient

ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12

Dim result As String = webClient.DownloadString("https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=bitcoin&vs_currencies=usd&include_market_cap=false&include_24hr_vol=false&include_24hr_change=false&include_last_updated_at=false&precision=full")
```

And its stored in variable result as json